# Alternatives to CRON for calling a script on a scheduled basis?

Tags: cron

I am trying to call a bash script on a scheduled basis (every 5 minutes at 0th and 5th minutes specifically) and was unable to get CRON to work with my CBL-Mariner docker implementation. Is there an alternative to CRON? I don't think a while loop with sleep would work as how do I guarantee it runs at the 0th and 5th minutes?

On a side note, is there a way to start the cron daemon in Mariner? In Ubuntu, I was able to just define my crontab and run "cron" to trigger the cron job. In mariner, I am unable to use systemctl to start crond.service as I get the following error: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.Failed to connect to bus: Host is down. Manually starting the cron daemon with crond or /usr/sbin/crond -n & doesn't work either. Any suggestions?